# По два цвета в массив

Tags: php

Добрый день.
Как можно с помощью php разделить цвета из текста?

Получаю 4 (любое четное число) цвета из textarea, каждый на новой строке.
Нужно разбить по 2 цвета на подмассивы (массив в массиве).

**Пример:**

**Получил $_POST['colors']:**

```
Красный

Красный

Черный

Синий
```

**Нужно из этого получить массив вида:**

```
$colors = array(array('Красный', Красный), array('Черный', 'Синий'));
```

Вопрос: как это сделать?

Я думаю нужно, как-то вот так:

```
$colors = explode('\n', $_POST['colors']);
```

Это все окей, но мне нужно по два цвета, а не по одному.

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)  - Разбивает массив на части

```
array array_chunk ( array $array , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
```

`array` - Обрабатываемый массив

`size` - Размер каждой части

`preserve_keys` - Если установлено в **TRUE**, ключи оригинального массива будут сохранены. По умолчанию установлено в **FALSE**, что переиндексирует каждую часть с числовыми ключами

#### Пример

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )
)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Это то, что нужно.